# メタトップページ上位の質問リスト下部にある人気タグ一覧が404になる

Tags: バグ, 完了

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/%24popularUrl に遷移しエラー画面が表示されます。

修正よろしくお願いします。

Comment: URLはどこのリンクからアクセスになっていますか？

Comment: @jmac [サイトトップ](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/)の一番下にある "質問をもっと見るには、全ての質問のリストか人気タグ一覧をご覧ください" の「人気タグ一覧」ですね。メインもメタもです。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。スクショの方貼らず申し訳ありません。